# Python: "no module named pip"

Tags: python, pip

I use Windows 7 32 bit and Python 3.7.

I was trying to install a module with pip and this error came up:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32
pip install pyttsx3
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\python 3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\python\python 3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.7\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: could you try `pip3 install pyttsx3` ?

Comment: ya it worked. Thanks, i am posting it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try?

```sh
pip3 install pyttsx3
```

Answer (score 41):

Make sure you have python path added to the `PATH` variable. Then run

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Comment: it is now throwing this error:
C:\Windows\System32>pip install pyttsx3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\python 3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\python\python 3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python\Python 3.7\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli'

Comment: try upgrading pip `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: ... unless that is what got you into this mess ;)

Comment: On a 2021 Macbook M1 I was getting `EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`. I had to run: `sudo python -m ensurepip` followed by `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. I find python dependencies to be quite challenging (:

Comment: "No module named ensurepip". Can I try "python -m ensureensurepip"? :)

Comment: thats toooo ensuring.. :D Just make sure the PATH variable is correctly set.

Answer (score 2):

To me, for [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa), the following helped:

```
ls -al /usr/bin/python # Check before removal that 'python' is link
sudo rm /usr/bin/python # Remove link to old version of python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python # Create new link to actual python version
sudo apt install python3-pip # Install missing pip
```

*"Python: No module named pip"* was because of missing `python3-pip`.

Answer (score 1):

Start Python Setup again ([Download from here](https://www.python.org/)) and be sure to tick that `Add python to PATH` at the bottom of installation.

Comment: Both python and python\scripts(where pip is) are in path

Comment: @NikunjMundhra Check whether they are in `System Variables`

Comment: they are, checked twice

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to a folder on your computer.
2. Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing the
   get-pip.py installer.
3. Run the following command:

   python get-pip.py
4. 4-) Verify Installation and Check the Pip Version:

   pip -V

Comment: The problem isn't that `pip` is not installed at all, because the `pip` command is running.  The problem is that during the execution of `pip`, an error occurs where the `pip` Module can't be found, not the executable.  It could be that `pip` is not completely or correctly installed, so reinstalling it might fix it, but some form of it is apparently already there.

Answer (score 1):

This command finally worked for me

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`